# Add different type variables into a vector

Tags: c++

I want to read data from a file into different types of variables and add them to a vector. The file has multiple lines with the same type of content separated by spaces (char, int, double, double, double, char). I created a class Atom:

```
class Atom {
    private:
    char Atom_Name;
    int Fixed;
    double X_cord;
    double Y_cord;
    double Z_cord;
    char Represent;
};
```

And my main function looks like that:

```
ifstream inFS;
string line;
string FileName = "File_Name.txt";
inFS.open(FileName);  
// Verify file opened correctly.
// Output error message and return 1 if file stream did not open correctly.
if (!inFS.is_open()) {
  cout << "Error opening " << FileName << endl;
  exit(1);
}
vector<Atom> Inputs;
while (getline(inFS, line)){
  istringstream ss(line);
  char name;
  int fixed;
  double x_c, y_c, z_c;
  char repr;
  ss >> name >> fixed >> x_c >> y_c >> z_c >> repr;
  for (int i = 0; i<704; i++){
    Inputs.push_back(name, fixed, x_c, y_c, z_c, repr);
  }
}
```

The error "main.cpp:38:12: error: no matching member function for call to 'push_back'
Inputs.push_back(name, fixed, x_c, y_c, z_c, repr);

Am I have to somehow override push_back function for multiple variables to be pushed?

Comment: `std::vector<Atom>::push_back()` expects just *one* `Atom` instance, not its members, if you want to construct a `Atom` object from its members, use `emplace_back`. For your case you are better off making your variables public instead of private since your class doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: You need to `push_back` an `Atom`. Define a ctor `Atom::Atom(char, int, double, double, double, char)` and then use `Inputs.push_back(Atom(name, fixed, x_c, y_c, z_c, repr));`

Comment: You can also [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) to use a constructor's parameter's to create an `Atom` directly in the `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your vector expects an Atom object not a list of parameters, create an object of atom first and intialize its parameters, so to start off create a constructor in your header file, so that you have something that looks like the following:

```
Atom::Atom(char name, int fixed, double x, double y, double z){
    this->name = name;
    this->fixed = fixed;
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
};
```

After this in your main file create an object of Atom and push it into your vector by calling the constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think this is exactly what I`m missing.

Comment: If this answered your question, you should really upvote and select it as the correct answer @Kleogis

Comment: I tried upvote, but it shows I can't because my rating is too low.

Comment: @Kleogis there should be a green checkmark up near up and down arrows. It doesn't show up right away to prevent people form selecting the first answer they see. Three days later you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: @YunfeiChen In this case it's because I had an answer for this question half written. By the time I got back to it, everything but [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) and loading the `Atom` with a `>>` overload had been covered. I figured dropping operator overloading on the questioner would be too much information and `emplace_back`'s not all that useful here (probably cheaper to copy the same temporary 704 times), so I made a comment under the question and upvoted the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `struct` if you just want to store variables in a group. Also, you need to pass an instance of `Atom` not its members to the vector.

Another problem is that the class you've defined has private members which is inaccessible anywhere in your code except the class itself. It has not a single member function to obtain their values, that's the reason of using `struct` here, its variables are visible anywhere, just need to be followed by a `.` (e.g. `atom.name` access `name` character array).

Do something like:

```
#include <vector>

struct Atom {
    char name[50]; // define the char array length too
    ...
};

int main(void) {
    Atom atom; // to push_back()
    std::vector<Atom> vecAtom;
    .
    std::cin >> atom.name >> ...;
    .
    vecAtom.push_back(atom); // passing a struct of `Atom` here
    .
    .
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was planning to write Get() functions for each of private parameters, but it probably easier just change class to a struct.

Comment: Remember that you can only hold variables with datatype in struct, not functions.